# Get Height of SVG String

Tags: text, svg, bounding-box

I'm trying to get the height of an SVG string. I'm getting the width with getComputedTextLength(), which works well, but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent for height.

getBBox() is not an option. It is no longer supported in Firefox, at least not for text, apparently because it is part of SVG 2.0.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "no longer supported", `getBBox` works fine at least on the <text> element in Firefox Nightly 34, I'm relatively sure this has been supported for a long time.

Comment: doesn't work for tspan though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Element you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`. have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) for documentation. In some Browsers the returned rect does not have a height property, but by simple subtracting `rect.bottom - rect.top` you got it.

Please not that `getBoundingClientRect()` will return values in absolute space, whereby `getBBox()` returns values in user space of the element, what can be confusing if it has applied transformations.

Answer (score 2):

`getBBox()` should work fine for text elements on Firefox.

[Here's a demo to prove it.](http://jsfiddle.net/8t1wy07o/)

This worked fine for me in FF 32.

Comment: Throws NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED on Firefox 31.1.0, Linux.

Comment: On the example in this answer? Or on some other case you have involving tspan/textPath?